# network handling and internet connection handling using mvvm with provider in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am getting error in onTap.
Error: The argument type 'Function' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'void Function()?'.

- 'Function' is from 'dart:core'.
  onTap: onTap

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import '../users_list/models/users_list_model.dart';
import 'app_title.dart';

class UserListRow extends StatelessWidget {
  final UserModel userModel;
  final Function onTap;
  UserListRow({required this.userModel, required this.onTap});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return InkWell(
      onTap: onTap,
      child: Container(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            AppTitle(text: userModel.name),
            Text(
              userModel.email,
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Figure out which line of code is causing the error, and troubleshoot it.  Think about what "The argument type 'Function' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'void Function()'" means.

Answer (score 0):

```
final Function onTap;
```

put parenthesis after Function,
change the above mentioned code to:

```
final Function()? onTap;
```